# Hadoop 2 node cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it necessary to have 2 linux machine for configuring two node hadoop cluster(ie 1 master 1 slave).Can it be done on single machine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run in local mode or pseudo-distributed mode, you don't necessarily need an actual cluster of machines.

See: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html

Comment: Hey Thanks but if i am running on cloud so where i will mention master and slave?

Comment: If you follow the instructions for configuration of pseudo-distributed mode I believe that should allow you to specify your setup there.

Comment: for masters you will not mention anywhere except for the SNN. The host names or IPs in the config files will take care. for all slave machines there should be entries made in slaves file

Comment: Here is another interesting [blog entry](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for setting up a single node.